# specifying path to node executable in mafefile on windows

Tags: node.js, makefile

My node executable is located in

```
C:\PROGRAM FILES\nodejs\node.exe
```

I would like to specify the path to this in my makefile which i am doing as below. This is the very first line in my makefile

```
NODE=-L"C:\PROGRAM FILES\nodejs" -lnode.exe
FOREVER=$(NODE) bin/node_modules/forever/bin/forever
PROTRACTOR_PATH=bin/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor
PROTRACTOR=$(NODE) $(PROTRACTOR_PATH)
```

when i run the make file I get the following error:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I have also tried specifying it using various other options

```
NODE=C:\PROGRAM\ FILES\nodejs\node.exe
NODE=-L"C:\PROGRAM\ FILES\nodejs"
NODE=-L"C:\\PROGRAM\ FILES\\nodejs"
NODE=-L"C:/PROGRAM FILES/nodejs"
```

None of the above work.

Error message received is :

```
 fatal error U1073: don't know how to make '-L"C:\\PROGRAM\'
```

Any ideas how to make my makefile work ?

Comment: Could you show us how the variable `NODE` (or a derivative) is used in a recipe ? Did you try `NODE=-L"C:/PROGRAM FILES/nodejs"` ?

Comment: That did not help.. see the update to my question above

Comment: Did you try replacing `PROGRAM FILES` with an alias without white space like `%programfiles%` ?